# compact commits when/after git merge

Tags: git, merge

For example:
I have branches: master, A

And when I work on `A`, there are some changes to `master` and these changes are important to A too, so `A` has to merge the `master` branch.
Then I commit some changes already made to `A`:

```
git commit -m "A process 2"
```

After merging, many commit logs dirt the log of branch `A`, the log of `A` will like this:

```
A process 3
merge master
log from master xxx
log from master yyy
log from master ....
...
A process 2
merge master
....
A process 1
```

Is there possible to compact those `log from master ...` messages to one message or just delete all of them because `merge master` message already explain everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do either of options you ask.  You can though pass all number of options to 'git log' which can suppress the commits from Master from showing up though.

The first one to try would be to list only commits reachable by A but not those reachable by master.

```
git log A ^master
```

Presuming you are using tracking branches, you can script something generic out that looks like

```
git log @{u}..HEAD
```

Which would log all changes on the current branch but not reachable from the upstream.